# Client side validation of user details

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, validation

I have been working on a project using validatorjs to check if a user's email corresponds to a given email format. If there's match, i want to set a property(role) to admin. Below is some code samples
client-side
**Register**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { setAlert } from '../../actions/alert'
import { register } from '../../actions/auth'
import Alert from './Alert'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { NavLink, Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter, Form, Input } from 'reactstrap'
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import contains from 'validator/lib/contains'

const Register = ({ setAlert, register, isAuthenticated }) => {
    const [
        formData,
        setFormData,
    ] = useState({
        name: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        password2: '',
        phone: '',
        address: '',
    })
    const [
        Role,
        setRole,
    ] = useState({
        role: 'user',
    })

    const { role } = Role

    const [
        modal,
        setModal,
    ] = useState(false)

    const toggle = () => setModal(!modal)

    const { name, email, password, password2, phone, address } = formData

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({
            ...formData,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
        })
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        if (password !== password2) {
            setAlert('Password do not match', 'danger')
        }

        if (contains(email, 'admin-') && contains(password, 'admin-')) {
            setRole({
                ...Role,
                role: 'admin',
            })
        }

        register({ name, email, password, phone, address, role })

        if (isAuthenticated) {
            setModal(!modal)
            setFormData({
                name: '',
                email: '',
                password: '',
                password2: '',
                phone: '',
                address: '',
                role: '',
            })
            return <Redirect to='/cars' />
        }
    }

    return (
        <Fragment>
            <NavLink color='danger' onClick={toggle}>
                Register
            </NavLink>
            <Modal isOpen={modal} toggle={toggle} centered>
                <ModalHeader toggle={toggle}>Register</ModalHeader>
                <Alert>
                    <Alert />
                </Alert>
                <ModalBody>
                    <div className=' '>
                        <Form className=''>
                            <Input
                                type='name'
                                placeholder='Name'
                                name='name'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className='mb-4 form-control-lg'
                                value={name}
                            />

                            <Input
                                type='email'
                                placeholder='Email'
                                name='email'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className='mb-4 form-control-lg'
                                value={email}
                            />

                            <Input
                                type='password'
                                placeholder='Password'
                                name='password'
                                minLength='4'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className='mb-4 form-control-lg'
                                value={password}
                            />

                            <Input
                                type='password'
                                placeholder='Confirm Password'
                                name='password2'
                                minLength='4'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className='mb-4 form-control-lg'
                                value={password2}
                            />

                            <Input
                                type='phone'
                                placeholder='Phone'
                                name='phone'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className='mb-4 form-control-lg'
                                value={phone}
                            />

                            <Input
                                type='address'
                                placeholder='Address'
                                name='address'
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                className='mb-4 form-control-lg'
                                value={address}
                            />
                        </Form>
                    </div>
                </ModalBody>
                <ModalFooter>
                    <Button color='primary' onClick={onSubmit}>
                        Submit
                    </Button>
                </ModalFooter>
            </Modal>
        </Fragment>
    )
}

Register.propTypes = {
    setAlert: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    register: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setAlert, register })(Register)
```

Above i tried using the validator-js library, to validate the email and password before passing down to the *register* action
**Server-side** code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const {
    check,
    validationResult
} = require('express-validator');
const User = require('../models/User');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const gravatar = require('gravatar');
const Admin = require('../models/Admin');

//user registration
router.post(
    '/register',
    [
        check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
        check('email', 'Enter a valid email address').isEmail(),
        check('password', 'password must be more than 4 characters and must be alphanumeric').isLength({
            min: 4
        }),
        check('phone', 'must be a number').isLength({
            max: 11
        }).isNumeric(),
        check('address', 'address is required').not().isEmpty()
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                errors: errors.array()
            })
        }
        const {
            email,
            password,
            name,
            phone,
            address,
            role
        } = req.body;

        try {
            if (role === 'admin') {
                let admin = await Admin.findOne({
                    email
                })

                if (admin) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        errors: [{
                            msg: 'Invalid credentials'
                        }]
                    });
                }

                admin = new Admin({
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    phone,
                    role
                });

                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                admin.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

                await admin.save();

                const payload = {
                    admin: {
                        id: admin.id
                    }
                }

                //jsonwebtoken hookup
                jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: 360000
                }, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.json({
                        token
                    });
                });

            } else {
                let user = await User.findOne({
                    email
                });

                if (user) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        errors: [{
                            msg: 'User already exists'
                        }]
                    });
                }

                const avatar = gravatar.url(email, {
                    s: '200',
                    r: 'pg',
                    d: 'mm'
                })

                user = new User({
                    name,
                    email,
                    password,
                    phone,
                    avatar,
                    address,
                    role
                });

                const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
                user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

                await user.save();

                const payload = {
                    user: {
                        id: user.id
                    }
                }

                //jsonwebtoken hookup
                jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                    expiresIn: 360000
                }, (err, token) => {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    res.json({
                        token
                    });
                });
            }

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error.message);
            res.status(500).json('Server Error')
        }
    }
);
```

Now the problem is, I keep getting "user" repeatedly, even when the conditions are met.
what is it that i'm doing wrong?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: The role constantly returns "user" even when the condition is met?

Comment: State updates are asynchronous, so the `setRole({ ...Role, role: 'admin' })` only enqueues a state update, `role` is still "user" when you `register({ name, email, password, phone, address, role })` on the next line.